# Angularjs view not displaying data returned from factory

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs

I set up a service that consumes a rails api that is returning json. The request comes back based on the console output as:

```
Resource {tests: Array[4], $promise: Promise, $resolved: true}
```

The problem I am having is nothing is displaying in my view. Do I need to convert the returned results somehow? When I ping that route via postman I get a json object as my result set.

I have the following set-up:

/service/test.js

```
  angular.module('myApp')
      .factory('Test', function($resource) {
        return $resource('http://api.myapp-dev.com:3000/tests/:id', { id: '@_id' },
        {
          'index': {
            method:'GET',
            headers: {
              'Authorization':'<a token>'
            },
            isArray: false
          }
    });
  });
```

/controllers/tests.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('TestsCtrl', function ($scope, Test) {
    $scope.tests = Test.index();
  });
```

views/tests.html

```
<div>
  <ul ng-repeat="test in tests">
    <li>{{ test.value }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: your factory is returning a promise object. Shouldn't you resolve the promise using `then` or `success`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like below in your controller.

```
Test.index(
  function(response) {
    $scope.tests = response.tests;
  },
  function(error) {
  }
)
```

There are also other ways to do this like.

```
Test.index().$promise.then(
  function(response) {
    $scope.tests = response.tests;
  },
  errorCallback
)
```